# Rails polymorphism - exception from Action Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble implementing polymorphism in between my Rails models.

The intended structure is that I have an object/model called a 'Test'.  Each Test has multiple Scenarios and multiple Runs.  Each Scenario and each Run has multiple Events.  On my 'show' view for Tests, I want to have a list of all events associated with it (through the Scenarios/Runs).

What I have as class definitions:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :scenarios
    has_many :runs
end

class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    has_many :events, :as => :eventhaver
end

class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    has_many :events, :as => :eventhaver
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :eventhaver, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The database is fully set up and contains a selection of records - 1 Test with 4 Scenarios and 2 Runs, each of which has 1 or 2 events.  But when I try to go to the show view for the Test:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Tests#show
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.eventhaver_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`eventhaver_id` = 1 AND `events`.`eventhaver_type` = 'Scenario'

This tells me that something isn't working with the polymorphism definitions, because it is looking for the abstract class/model 'eventhaver' instead of the child classes 'Scenario' and 'Run'.  What else do I have to do so that Rails makes the connection and looks for either scenario_id or run_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a integer column `eventhaver_id` and a string column `eventhaver_type` in your `events` table.

The error tells you, that at least the column `eventhaver_id` is missing.

If you have the coloumns `scenario_id` and `run_id` in your `events` table, you can delete them. Polymorphic associations only use the `*abstract*_id`,`*abstract*_type` interface.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

*Edit*:
If you can't change your database you can use `:has_many, :through` plus a `events` method to access all `event` belonging to a `test`.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scenarios
  has_many :runs
  has_many :scenario_events, through: :scenarios, source: :events
  has_many :run_events, through: :runs, source: :events

  def events
    scenario_events + run_events
  end 
end


class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :events
end


class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :events
end


class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :run
  belongs_to :scenario
end
```

Comment: I don't have the option of changing the database, as this is being populated by another application.  So it sounds like polymorphism is not the right solution for what I am trying to produce - is there another technique I can use to maintain the scenario_id/run_id design?

Comment: thanks, how would the routes look for this solution?

I think it would be:

    resources :tests do
      resources :scenarios do
        resources :events
      ends
      resources :runs do
        resources :events
      end
    end

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve with new route here. You can use the default route for `test#show` (e.g. `/tests/1`). If you have something like `@test = Test.find(params[:id])`  in your controller, the events are accessible with `@test.events` inside the view.